# In rsreportserver.config file, how can I set CSV export to have a field delimiter of none

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

In rsreportserver.config file, how can I set CSV export to have a field delimiter of none So that I can extract a fixed length file? I tried keeping it empty but it gives commas after each field value. 
Also if possible, please provide the script to get fixed length file and some of the fields can have commas in between values.

I would really appreciate any input as my client is fully determined to use SSRS and not SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a new custom extension

use the following as an example :

```
<Extension Name="csvnoseperator" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
                <OverrideNames>
                    <Name Language="en-US">csvnoseperator</Name>
                </OverrideNames>
                <Configuration>
                    <DeviceInfo>
                        <FieldDelimiter></FieldDelimiter>
                        <UseFormattedValues>False</UseFormattedValues>
                        <NoHeader>True</NoHeader>
                        <Encoding>ASCII</Encoding>
                        <FileExtension>csv</FileExtension>
                    </DeviceInfo>
                </Configuration>
            </Extension>
```

You should be able to then use this as an export format from the front end.

Please ensure you backup your config file before you make this change! If you get it wrong, you will not be able to starts Reporting Service